# Jsoup - Extract from html string with the same span class name

Tags: html, jsoup

I'm still new to html. For an Android project, I need to extract some data from an html string using jsoup. The structure is something like this. All the span tags have the same class name. And the data I need is in between each of those.

```
<span class="head">a</span>
xxxx data xxxx
<span class="head">b</span>
xxxx data xxxx
<span class="head">c</span>
xxxx data xxxx
```

Is there any way I could extract it?

Comment: Show me what you have done so far. We'll start from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 things you have to do:

- select all elements that preceding the text node you are interested in,
- use `nextSibling` method to get the text node.

Take a look at this sample code:
    import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
    import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
    import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
    import org.jsoup.nodes.TextNode;

```
public class JsoupExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String html = "<span class=\"head\">a</span>\n" +
                "xxxx data xxxx\n" +
                "<span class=\"head\">b</span>\n" +
                "xxxx data xxxx\n" +
                "<span class=\"head\">c</span>\n" +
                "xxxx data xxxx";

        Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);

        for (Element span : document.select("span.head")) {
            TextNode node = (TextNode) span.nextSibling();

            assert "xxxx data xxxx".equals(node.text());

            System.out.println(node.text());
        }
    }
}
```

It uses your input and shows both steps.

Here `document.select("span.head")` we select all elements with class `head`, then we iterate over those elements using `forEach(span -> {})` function and lambda expression (this is Java 8 example). Then we get interesting text node using: `TextNode node = (TextNode) span.nextSibling();` Here we just check if text node equals the value we expect by using assertion and we simply display it to standard output.

Modify this code sample for your needs. I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you for explaining it so well. But unfortunately, lambda support for Android seems to be quite hacky for now.

Comment: Hey @arjerine, Java 8 is not a problem since it was only used for iterating and printing node text. I changed the sample to be Java 6/7 compatible. The solution you are looking for is the `nextSibling` method used properly, I hope it is shown in the exemplary code sample.

Comment: nextSibling() to TextNode throws ClassCastException for some odd reason. But anyway, I managed to get the data by slightly tweaking the code. Thanks again @SzymonStepniak

Comment: You might have a wrong `TextNode` class imported. Check if imported `TextNode` is equal to `org.jsoup.nodes.TextNode`. I can imagine that there might be another TextNode class in Android platform that lays in totally different package. Cheers!

Comment: I'm also getting the ClassCastException even though Element and TextNode are from org.jsoup.nodes. @goat Can you share what you did to tweak this?

Answer (score 0):

> Try this code working fine.

```
public class JsoupExample {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String html = "<span class=\"head\">a</span>\n" +
            "xxxx data xxxx\n" +
            "<span class=\"head\">b</span>\n" +
            "xxxx data xxxx\n" +
            "<span class=\"head\">c</span>\n" +
            "xxxx data xxxx";

    Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);

    for (Element element: document.select("span.head")) {
        System.out.println(element.text());
    }
}
```

}